# Weird characters when printing out strings in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm currently working on a program that reads strings from a file and stores them into a 2-D array. However, when I try to print out the contents of the array, I get a random character every time. Here is my code:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE* file_pointer;
    char user_input[80];
    char line[81];
    char all_lines_array[100][81];
    int total_lines = 0;
    while (1){
        printf("Please enter a command: ");
        scanf("%s", &user_input);
        if (strstr(user_input, "read") != NULL){
            file_pointer = fopen("C:\\Users\\Tyler\\Desktop\\Hello.txt","r");
            while (fgets(line, 100, file_pointer)) {
                line[strlen(line)+1] = "\0";
                *all_lines_array[total_lines] = line; //My guess is this is wrong
                total_lines++;
        }
        fclose(file_pointer);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I suspect that this is because I'm incorrectly inserting string into my 2-D array, but I have no idea what it is I'm doing wrong. I've set the numbers so that there can only be a maximum of 100 lines in a file, and each line can only be 80 characters long (with the `"\0"` at the end).

Here is my input file:

```
John Doe    1221 Washington St.    1234567
Jane Doe    1233 Washington St.    1234568
Cain Doe    1234 Washington St.    1234569
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fgets is reading 100 chars but your static allocated variable `char line[81]` is only allocates memory for 81 chars.
instead of the `=` operator use `strcpy`

Comment: Thank you, strcpy worked. Might I ask what strcpy does?

Comment: when i had to program C, i always looked up functions like strcpy on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) or [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/) there you get all information you need including examples!

Comment: @MistFTW It copies data from one C string/array to another, and may be duped into corrupting memory in the process if `'\0'` terminator chars are missing. Which is one reason why you should really read the docs to evaluate the answer instead of trusting blindly! (Not that this one is fatally flawed, just that with C taking random code on the Internet at 'its word' is not a smart thing to do!)

Comment: a little thing i want to add: when working with string functions on C you have to be very careful, that you always have memory allocated for the '\0' character and you should lookup all string functions on the reference pages because some add the '\0' char and some do not.

Answer (score 1):

There where some statements flagged when compiling with `-Wall` [which I always recommend doing], which may have helped with some of the errors.

Here's the corrected version, annotated with comments [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main()
{
    FILE *file_pointer;
    char user_input[80];
    char line[81];
    char all_lines_array[100][81];
    int total_lines = 0;

    while (1) {
        printf("Please enter a command: ");

        // compiler flagged this with a warning
#if 0
        scanf("%s", &user_input);
#else
        scanf("%s", user_input);
#endif

        if (strstr(user_input, "read") != NULL) {
#ifndef CRAIG
            file_pointer = fopen("C:\\Users\\Tyler\\Desktop\\Hello.txt", "r");
#else
            file_pointer = fopen("input.txt", "r");
#endif
            if (file_pointer == NULL) {
                printf("file not found\n");
                continue;
            }

            // NOTE: using sizeof here is better as 100 was specified but
            // "line" was only 81
            while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file_pointer)) {
                // NOTE: I presume this is to strip the newline
                // in the original form, it would add garbage chars to the end
                // [because of "\0" instead of '\0']
#if 0
                line[strlen(line) + 1] = "\0";
#else
                line[strlen(line) - 1] = 0;
#endif

                // NOTE: the compiler flagged this as well
#if 0
                *all_lines_array[total_lines] = line;   // My guess is this is wrong
#else
                strcpy(all_lines_array[total_lines],line);
#endif
                total_lines++;
            }

            fclose(file_pointer);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```